# Python - Scrape Javascript using bs4 and print out the value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to create a script where there is a countdown with epoch time which I later gonna convert it.

The html is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                new Countdown('countdown_timer', '1547161260', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
            </script>
```

and I started to scrape it which I managed to scrape using:

```
try:
    time_countdown_tag = bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
except Exception:
    time_countdown_tag = []

for countdown in time_countdown_tag:
    if 'new Countdown' in countdown.text.strip():
        print(countdown)
```

which my output is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                new Countdown('countdown_timer', '1547161260', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
            </script>
```

However what I want to print out in this case is the number inside the params which is **1547161260** - I would appreciate all kind of help to be able to be able to only print out the number (epoch) if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to match the portion of the JS that contains a positive integer:

```
import re
output = """<script type="text/javascript">
                new Countdown('countdown_timer', '1547161260', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
            </script>"""
re.findall("\d+", output)
```

Comment: Hello! Oh yeah! However I do get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I try this code :O could it be becuase of the spaces \t ?

Comment: My guess is to do maybe `countdown.text.strip()` before doing `re.findall("\d+", output)`

Comment: That would work. I'm guessing you're passing in `countdown` which is an object, and `countdown.text` (or `str(countdown)`) would be the string representation.

Comment: Exactly, I guess thats what my thoughts were, It did work when I passed it as a text.